# MX Anywhere 2 not showing in scan on XPS 13 (9360)

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, dell, 17.04

I am on XPS 13 (9360) trying to pair MX Anywhere 2 via bluetooth, however the mouse doesn't even show up in the scan list. I can verify that the bluetooth is working as I have succesfully paired the bluetooth speaker. The mouse do show up on my phone/windows machine, but just not on Ubuntu 17.04 that I'm running on.

```
$ lspci
3a:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)

$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ uname -r
4.10.0-21-generic
```

I also tried `bluetoothctl` and did a scan while MX Anywhere 2 is blinking, still not detecting the mouse. I had the XPS dual boot to windows and paired there, when I re-boot to Ubuntu 17.04, the mouse came up under the bluetooth scan list but goes off later when rebooted. It's annoying to go back and forth to windows for the mouse to show up in Ubuntu.

Is there any fix to this specific issue? It doesn't look like neither the bluetooth driver or the mouse is faulty.

Also, could it be something with the driver?

```
$ service bluetooth status
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-06-01 23:09:45 EDT; 19min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 719 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─719 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jun 01 23:09:45 xps-13 bluetoothd[719]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Jun 01 23:09:45 xps-13 bluetoothd[719]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
Jun 01 23:09:45 xps-13 bluetoothd[719]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Jun 01 23:09:45 xps-13 bluetoothd[719]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Jun 01 23:09:45 xps-13 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jun 01 23:09:46 xps-13 bluetoothd[719]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.29 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jun 01 23:09:46 xps-13 bluetoothd[719]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.29 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jun 01 23:09:52 xps-13 bluetoothd[719]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.58 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jun 01 23:09:52 xps-13 bluetoothd[719]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.58 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jun 01 23:09:52 xps-13 bluetoothd[719]: RFCOMM server failed for Headset Voice gateway: rfcomm_bind: Address already in use (98)
```